# Java Applet Error In Browser - java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, applet

I'm trying to run my first java applet in my browser but when I open the HTML file which the applet class is embedded into, the following error occurs:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$12.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission user.dir read)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
at Applet.MAIN.<clinit>(MAIN.java:39)
... 21 more
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Here is the: [entire error block](http://www.dltube.ir/jup/applet.txt)

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applet has limited permissions. Non-signed applet cannot access file system and part of the system properties. In your case you tried to access `user.dir`.

You have the following solutions.

1. try to avoid using user.dir
2. sign your applet
3. do not use applet at all. Use java web start instead.

Comment: i have to use user.dir but i signed my applet , still does not work :(

Comment: `user.dir` does not point to a reproducible path.  It is hazardous to rely on it even in a conventional desktop app., madness to do so in an applet.  What does the applet actually do?

Comment: the use.dir part provides the image address on the hardware for HTML part of the code .

Comment: Re. point 3.  JWS will typically not solve security problems.  Applets and JWS apps. share a very (very) similar `SecurityManager`.  OTOH JWS offers the [JNLP API](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html), but that would require code changes.

Answer (score 0):

Youre trying to access something you dont have permission to

```
  Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission user.dir read)
```

You can sign your applet

And/or set the permissions in the users home directory

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/permissions.html